# MVC 4 External Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I will made a sample code just to describe my problem, here is the code that I originally use on the view:

```
@model MyProject.Web.UI.ViewModels.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('Test');
        });

        ... more code here (removed for brevity)
    </script>
}
```

This one is working well, but as a good practice, I need to move the javascript/jquery code to an external file so the above code turned into this:

```
@model MyProject.Web.UI.ViewModels.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@section scripts{
    <script src="/Js/external-js-file.js">
    </script>
}
```

and in my external javascript/jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Test');
});

... more code here (removed for brevity)
```

and to my surprise, the alert wasn't even firing, all of the jquery and javascript code is suddenly not working, I've been googling a lot and I can't find any solution to this, am I missing something? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Check your console for errors - is the file being loaded?

Comment: yup, definitely, I've viewed the page source and the file is actually loaded.

Comment: Press `F12` in your browser and refresh.. see if you are getting 404 or any other error.

Comment: just to confirm. Have you included jQuery. If included it must be before this script

Comment: Yup iJay, I included it before the external javascript.
Rosdi, no 404 error man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys nevermind I've found the culprit! I've copy & paste the javascript code and I found out that there is a server side comment included on the script, stupid me.

```
@* razor comment *@
```

I appreciate the prompt reply guys, next time I'll be more careful.